# Replace the value with the sum of two previous values in python by group

Tags: python, loops, cumsum

I have the following dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame ({'Date':['2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2000-03-01','2000-04-01','2000-05-01',
                             '2000-01-01', '2000-02-01','2000-03-01'
                           
                           ],
                  
                     'id':['1', '1', '1', '1','1','2', '2', '2'],
                   
                    'error': [0, 0.8, 'nan', 'nan', 'nan', 2.5, 0.25, 'nan']


                                     
                    })
```

I need to replace 'nan' with the sum of the previous values and then start all over. For example,

if Date= ' 2000-03-01' and id = 1, error = 0.1 * 0.8 + 0.2 * 0 =0.08

if Date = ' 2000-04-01' and id = 1, error = 0.1 * 0.08 + 0.2 * 0.8 = 0.168

if Date = '2000-05-01 and id = 1, error = 0.1 * 0.168 + 0.2 * 0.08 = 0.0328
etc.

I tried to do the following:

```
df['error'] = pd.to_numeric(df.error, errors = 'coerce')

df['error'] =(df.groupby('id')
    .apply(lambda x: 0.1*x.error.shift(1) + 0.2 * x.error.shift(2).cumsum())
    .reset_index('id', drop = True)
    )
```

but it does not work.  The data I should get is below:

Does anyone know how to do it in Python?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following is an iterative solution, assuming that the first two values of each group are not nan.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2000-03-01', '2000-04-01', '2000-05-01',
                            '2000-01-01', '2000-02-01', '2000-03-01'
                            ],
                   'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
                   'error': [0, 0.8, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2.5, 0.25, np.nan]
                   })

idx = df[df['error'].isna()].index 
for i in idx: 
     df.loc[i, 'error'] = 0.1*df.loc[i-1, 'error'] + 0.2*df.loc[i-2, 'error']
```

Comment: Thank you, Pramote. It helps a lot. Do I need to use groupby('id') or not in this case? I just want to make sure that the i-1 and i-2 values are not taken from another customer.

Comment: To make sure, you can group by id or you can use df.sort_values('id') .

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Pramote, where should I put in 'groupby(['id'])?

Comment: If the first two values of group are not NaN, use df = df.sort_values('id') before idx = ...  It is easier.